# Preprocessing: text analysis on many columns from a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Using the following lines it is possible to preprocess text in a specific column of my dataframe:

```
#text to lower case
df$name <- tolower(df$name)
#remove all special characters
df$name <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", df$name)
#remove long spaces
df$name <- gsub("\\s+"," ",str_trim(df$name))
```

I would like to implement this preprocessing rules in all columns (expect id) of a dataframe like this:

```
df  <- data.frame(id = c("A","B","C"), D = c("mytext 11","mytext +", "!!"), E = c("text","stg","1.2"), F = c("press","remove","22"))
```

Comment: you should supply a data sample if you wish to receive answers

Comment: @Seymour as you can see I provide sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do something multiple times, it is often useful to define a [function.](https://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html)

For example, you could do the following:

```
library(stringr)
df  <- data.frame(id = c("A","B","C"), D = c("mytext 11","mytext +", "!!"), 
                  E = c("text","stg","1.2"), F = c("press","remove","22"))

# create a function so we can apply this multiple times easily.
process <- function(my_vector)
{
  my_vector <- tolower(my_vector)
  #remove all special characters
  my_vector <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", my_vector)
  #remove long spaces
  my_vector <- gsub("\\s+"," ",str_trim(my_vector))
  # return result
  return(my_vector)
}

# for all columns except 'id', apply our function.
for(x in setdiff(colnames(df),"id"))
{
 df[[x]]=process(df[[x]])
}
```

Comment: Why anybody would prefer the base R syntax above (`for(x in setdiff ...`) to `mutate_at()` is beyond me, especially as the OP is already in the Hadley-verse and using `stringr` ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr::mutate_at()` to mutate multiple columns; in this case, all columns *except for* `id`:

```
mydf %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(-id),
            .funs = processText)
```

Where `processText` is a function containing your desired code:

```
processText <- function(str) {
str %>%
    str_to_lower() %>%
    str_replace_all(pattern="[[[:punct:]]]|[\\s+]", replacement=" ", .) %>%
    str_trim()
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
  id         D    E      G
1  A mytext 11 text  press
2  B    mytext  stg remove
3  C            1 2     22
```