# Preprocessing text data on many columns from a data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp

I'm looking for an answer [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032578/preprocessing-text-analysis-on-many-columns-from-a-dataframe) this but in python. How can I do text preprocessing on multiple columns? I have two text columns see [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WvUp.png). To do the cleaning work, I have to do twice to each column (see my code). Is there any clever way to do a similar task? Thanks!

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #html.parser'
df['Summary'] = [BeautifulSoup(text).get_text() for text in df['Summary']]
df['Text'] = [BeautifulSoup(text).get_text() for text in df['Text']]


df.loc[:,"Text"] = df.Text.apply(lambda x : str.lower(x))
df.loc[:,"Summary"] = df.Summary.apply(lambda x : str.lower(x))   

#remove punctuation.
df["Text"] = df['Text'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
df["Summary"] = df['Summary'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
```

Comment: `df[['Text', 'Summary']] = df[['Text', 'Summary']].applymap(lambda x : x.lower().replace('[^\w\s]',''))`

Comment: Hi Michael,  thanks for your suggestions. Do I understand right that your code will lower the text characters as well as remove those punctuations? I removed the str to lower and punctuation part in my code and tried with your code, I found the punctuation was not removed. Can you have a look? Thanks. Here is the result, see next comment...

Comment: Forgot pythons replace doesn't have regex.  This should work.  `df[['Text', 'Summary']] = df[['Text', 'Summary']].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s]',''))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this code**

***USING REGEX:***

```
import re

def preprocess_text(text):
    """ Apply any preprocessing methods"""
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
    return text

df["Text"] = df.Text.apply(preprocess_text)
df["Summary"] = df.Summary.apply(preprocess_text)
```

***USING STRING LIBRARY:***

```
from string import punctuation
def preprocess_text(text):
    """ Apply any preprocessing methods"""
    text = text.lower()
    text = ''.join(c for c in text if c not in punctuation)
    return text

df["Text"] = df.Text.apply(preprocess_text)
df["Summary"] = df.Summary.apply(preprocess_text)
```

Note: To know more about the preprocessing task for text, you can read this blog https://medium.com/@pemagrg/pre-processing-text-in-python-ad13ea544dae

Comment: I like to put everything in a function. But it seems the code did not remove all punctuations. Like it happened before to  the last solution, the regex problem

Comment: Hi! @PemaGrg, here is the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KpgVKcTBCZRlSXC5arNEGIkw_32cTrHn/view?usp=sharing  Thanks!